# How to delete email with javax.email?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I have already seen another similar posts but it is still not working. I am using `javax.email` with `Gmail` and I can read messages successfully , but when I want to delete them, it does not do anything... I am doing this:

```
    // Open folder
    this.folder = this.store.getFolder("Inbox");
    this.folder.open(Folder.READ_WRITE);

    // Get messages with specified filters
    messages = this.folder.search(messagesFilters);

    // Delete
    message[0].setFlag(Flag.DELETED,true);

    // Close
    this.folder.expunge();
    this.folder.close(true);
    this.store.close();
```

But nothing happens in `Gmail`. Do you know how to do it?

Comment: I fixed it! Actually, i don't know what was happening but now it is working. Thanks